# CSS Isolations sees base class as different class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I don't know whether or not it is a design desicion by the blazor team.

If you have a base class which provides you some Markup like the following:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace BugBaseClass.Shared
{
    public abstract class BaseComponent : ComponentBase
    {
        protected static MarkupString SayHelloWorld()
        {
            return new("<p>Hello World</p>");
        }
    }
}
```

Use this in a component with the name `MyComponent.razor` like this:

```cs
@inherits BaseComponent

<div class="my-content">
    <p>From derived class</p>
    @SayHelloWorld()
</div>
```

And add some styling with CSS-Isolation. So name the css like the component:

**MyComponent.razor.css**:

```css
::deep p {
    background-color: yellow;
}


p {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Then the one from the base class is `yellow` (Hello World) and the one from the derived class is `red` ("From derived class"). If you remove the `::deep p` there is no styling at all.

Example:

[image: example]

My question is whether or not this is a design decision or more or less a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is by design.

Did you expect "Hello World" to be red?  `SayHelloWorld` is a member of the base class and not `MyComponent` and gets rendered by the `Renderer` in the context of `BaseComponent`.

The generated code is shown below.  Note that Html markup from `MyComponent` has the Css id, while the content from `BaseComponent` doesn't.  It's child content, so `deep::` works.

```
<div class="my-content" b-slw7z4imhe>
<p b-slw7z4imhe>From derived class</p>
<p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Razor code gets re-compiled into `RenderFragments` which are delegates run by the Renderer, not strings of Html markup.

Here's the c# class for `MyComponent`:

```
public partial class MyComponent : BaseComponent
{
    protected override void BuildRenderTree(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
    {
        __builder.OpenElement(0, "div");
        __builder.AddAttribute(1, "class", "my-content");
        __builder.AddAttribute(2, "b-slw7z4imhe");
        __builder.AddMarkupContent(3, "<p b-slw7z4imhe>From derived class</p>\r\n    ");
        __builder.AddContent(4, SayHelloWorld());
        __builder.CloseElement();
    }
}
```

Note the Id added to only the Razor generated content.  The Id is added by the Razor pre-compiler at compile time.  The programmer has no access to this generated Id and therefore can't use it.

This severely limits what you can do with it.  You must use `::deep` for all styles on your own code which sort of negates the "uniqueness".

Comment: Yes my expectation was exactly that. Furthermore if you add any function which returns a MarkupString it needs the `::deep` pseudo-selector.
If you add this to MyComponent.razor:
```
@Get()

@code {
    private MarkupString Get() => new ("<p>Get</p>");
    }
}
```
This will get yellow as the information is not available during compile time.

Comment: See my comment at the end of the answer.  I rarely use component Css for this very reason, preferring standard css files with unique names or use the same methodology as component Css, but with a known Id.